# Toggle arrow on click of dropdown (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 has default caret, on click of the dropdown I would like to change the caret as an upward arrow.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button> <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t2ma8q?file=index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the `::after` pseudo element and rotate it 180 degrees when the dropdown is shown:

```
  .dropdown.show button::after {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
  }
```

[Demo](https://www.bootply.com/tsmWWEmSqv)